# Should I always use "in" after "interested"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I wrote:

> There are some answers for that question you may be interested to read and answer yourself.

Should it be:

> There are some answers for that question you may be interested in reading and answering yourself.

Comment: Even though some native speakers will find the infinitive complement marginal or a little jarring or rather formal, it is a very well attested usage, and you can use it or **in reading**, whichever you prefer.  Others may feel the same about the prepositional phrase with -ing, or that it is rather informal. But it too is very well attested.

Comment: You don't need **it** before **yourself**

Answer (score 1):

usually but not always.

Examples

"you may be interested **to** learn *that* ..."

"you may be interested **in** reading this book/essay/poem "